# Python сравнение двух таблиц sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Есть таблица с отдельными никами, а есть таблица с несколькими никами в 1 строке, к примеру:

Таблица 1:

> ('AbdulaAlhazred',), ('Fanzy',), ('Mariyam',), ('hardY',), ('inwar',), ('pandora',), ('wh4OOOO',)]

Таблица 2:

> [('korak4ik, Mnxanj, DEMONcapustka, hardY',), ('wh4OOOO, Mnxanj',), ('Dark_warrior_3, GartyS, ERikson5512, NeOleg, VebDrocher',)]

Нужно сравнить 2 эти таблицы и совпадение вывести.

Код:

```
import sqlite3
base = sqlite3.connect('ЧС.db')
cur = base.cursor()

#Таблица 1
base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, id INT)')
base.commit()
#Таблица 2
base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list(NAME TEXT, PLAYERS TEXT, QUANTITY INT)')
base.commit()

x = cur.execute('SELECT name FROM data').fetchall()
print(x, '\n\n\n')
y = cur.execute('SELECT PLAYERS FROM list').fetchall()
print(y, '\n\n\n')

for r in y:
    if r[0] == x:
        print("Найдено совпадение {0}".format(r[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил не заморачиваться со сравнением списков и просто перевел в строку.

```
for user in y:
        for item in user:
            for i in x: 
                exist = "{}".format(i[0]) in item
                if exist == True:
                    await ctx.send('Найдено совпадение {}'.format(i[0]))
```